# $f$ differentiable with f(0)=0, 1 isn't eigenvalue of $f'(0)$. There's a neighborhood of 0 in wich $f(x)\neq x$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Question:**

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable with $f(0)=0$. If $1$ isn't eigenvalue of $f'(0)$ then there is a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in V\setminus\{0\}$.

I tried three approaches:

We know that $f'(0)x=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tx)}{t}\neq x$.

Also, $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f'(0)h}{||h||}=0$.

And $f(x)=f'(0)x+r(x)$ where $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{r(x)}{||x||}=0.$

And there's the fact that $f'(0)x\neq x$, $\forall x\in V\setminus \{0\}$.

But I don't know how to use theses facts here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** First consider the sphere $S^{m-1}$, then as the operator $f'(0)$ does not have a fixed point in $S^{m-1}$ there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that 
$$|u | = 1 \implies |f'(0)\cdot u - u |\geq \varepsilon $$

Now use the differentiability of $f$,that is,

$$f(x)=f(x) - f(0)= f'(0)\cdot x + \rho (x) \cdot |x| = |x|\left(f'(0)\cdot \frac{x}{|x|} + \rho (x)\right) \,\,,\,\, \lim_{x\to 0} \rho(x) = 0$$

to show that $|f(x) - x| > 0$.

Think you take it from here?

Comment: Then $f(x)-x=|x|\left(f'(0)\cdot \frac{x}{|x|} -\frac{x}{|x|}+\rho(x)\right)$, but then $(f(x)-x)\notin ]|x|(-\epsilon+\rho(x)),|x|(\epsilon+\rho(x))[$, as $\rho(x)$ is small, $0\in]|x|(-\epsilon+\rho(x)),|x|(\epsilon+\rho(x))[$, then $f(x)-x\neq 0$. Correct?

Comment: The first implication is correct. Now, just notice that for that same $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0 $ such that $$|x|  < \delta \implies |\rho (x)| < \varepsilon \implies -|\rho (x)| > - \varepsilon$$ 

Use that $|a + b| \geq |a| - |b|$ to get the wanted result.

Comment: I think the second implication is also correct for the same fact,
$$|\rho(x)|<\epsilon\Rightarrow -\epsilon+\rho(x)<0<\epsilon+\rho(x),$$
(that was what I meant by '$\rho(x)$ is small') then $0$ is in that set.

Comment: I see, always try to keep the writing as clean as possible though.